# Jquery slideup slidedown unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a lot of similar questions but could not find the answer which could solve my problem.

I have a div with id 'first'. All I want is slidedown another div with id 'second' over the first one when mouse is on div 'one' and slideup div 'second' when the mouse is out of that div.

The code below works well but it has some problems.

1) when the mose is in - it slides twice.

2) when the second div is down and I move mouse over the div, it slides again

Could you please help me to get the result I want.

**html**

```
<div>
<div id="zero"><div>
<div id="my_hover">
    <div id="second"></div>
     <div id="first"></div>
</div>
<div id="third"></div>  
</div>
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#first").mouseenter(function(){
   $("#second").stop().slideDown("slow");
  });
  $("#first").mouseout(function(){
   $("#second").slideUp("slow");
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add `pointer-events: none;` to the `#second` div CSS and position it above the `#first` div.

> `pointer-events: none;` In addition to indicating that the element is not the target of mouse events, the value `none` instructs the mouse event to go "through" the element and target whatever is "underneath" that element instead.
> (...)
>   The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, mouse events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event capture/bubble phases.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var slide = $("#second");
    $("#first").hover(function(){
        slide.stop().slideDown("slow");
    },function(){
        slide.slideUp("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
#first { 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background:red; 
}

#second {
    position: absolute; 
    display: none; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background:blue;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="second">Second</div>
<div id="first">First</div>
```

---

Another way is to insert these two elements inside another element and use `hover` for that element instead of div `#first`. This way, the whole area is sensitive:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var slide = $("#second");
    $(".my-hover").hover(function(){
        slide.stop().slideDown("slow");
    },function(){
        slide.slideUp("slow");
    });

    //for demo:
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        alert('it works!');
    });
 
});
```

```css
#first { 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background:red; 
}

#second {
    position: absolute; 
    display: none; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=my-hover>
    <div id="second"><button class=btn>BUTTON</button></div>
    <div id="first">First</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: It prevents mouse interaction.

Comment: @EducateYourself Yes. Updated answer with reference to `pointer-events`

Comment: Using `pointer-events: none;` is a bad practice, IMO. Suppose OP wants to add a button to the second div, then that button will not be clickable any more.

Comment: @EducateYourself That's why I posted another solution. It makes more sense overall. Just nest the two divs inside another (second example)

Comment: it works :) I also have another little problem and maybe you can help me. I have just edited my html code so that you could understand the situation. I have another div with id="zero" above the "my-hover" div and in the result, 'second' div slides down over the 'zero' div instead of 'first' div.

Comment: @EducateYourself , it sounds like positioning issue. It works on [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f37xhmw2/). PS. you have to close this `zero` div (missing closing slash)

Comment: Your code works fine but I cannot understand what is wrong with my css code. I just copied my css code in the fiddle. Could you please have a look. http://jsfiddle.net/EducateYourself/qrptoren/4/

Comment: @EducateYourself , add `clear:both;` CSS rule to `#my_hover` - [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qrptoren/5/) (it's because you're using `float:left` on your divs)

Answer (score 1):

Okay here you go :

```js
var $second=$("#second");

$("#first").hover(function(){
   $second.stop().slideDown("slow");
},function(){
   $second.stop().slideUp("slow");
  });
```

```css
div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left ;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#second{
  display: none;
  background: yellow;
  pointer-events : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="first">1</div>
<div id="second">2</div>
```

Comment: thanks but I want the second div to slidedown OVER the first one. Sorry for not mentioning that. I have edited my question.

Comment: No problem. Three more lines of CSS. Answer updated.

Comment: great! you solved the first problem. but the second one still exists. I don't want it to slideup when the mouse is moving inside the div but only when the mouse leaves the div box.

Comment: I see the first problem is not solved as well. it still slides several times and when gets to the mouse cursor, it cannot slidedown farther.

Comment: Uh? It works perfectly fine for me. The div 2 slides down completely, then keeps down as long as the mouse is over div 1. What browser are you using?

Comment: I have added `pointer-events:none` on div 2, this should do the trick.

Comment: Damn, I arrived too late. It's already been proposed and accepted as an answer. Too bad.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code and it's working well:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#first").mouseenter(function(){
   $("#second").stop().slideDown("slow");
  });
  $("#first").mouseout(function(){
   $("#second").slideUp("slow");
  });
 });
```

See Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/dwxxpabq/

Comment: I want the second div to slidedown OVER the first one. Sorry for not mentioning that. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the second `div` as a child of first `div` and by using relative/absolute positioning you can achieve what you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var slide = $("#second");
  $("#first").hover(function() {
    slide.stop().slideDown("slow");
  }, function() {
    slide.slideUp("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
#first {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
#second {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="first">First
  <div id="second">Second
    <button>click me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```